# Is there any dart library for the Google Authenticator?

Tags: dart, flutter, google-authenticator

I'm looking for a way to implement/connect the Google-Authenticator into Flutter/Dart. The goal is to be able to validate codes generated in the Google-Authenticator app to create a two-step authentication.

Maybe I'm blind, but due to the name, it's really hard to find anything on it (thanks to the word "authenticator"). The best I could find so far was a PHP port: https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/google-authenticator

I'm having trouble to even just find an API Documentation on the Authenticator.

Before I start to write my own implementation: Is there any implementation for Dart already? Where can I find the Google-Authenticator documentation?

Edit 1: clarified the part about implementing Google-Authenticator (to verify codes).

Comment: Are you looking for something like this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/google_sign_in ?

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky does that library include Google Authenticator Support? I looked into it briefly, but didn't see it mentioned anywhere in the docs. I basically already have a login / auth mechanism, I just want to implement the two-way authentication of Google Authenticator (the app that generates codes)

Comment: Actually, I don't know - I didn't use this library in flutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello @Katai I suppose this functionality is a little hard to find due to the terms, but also because it usually gets mixed up / confused with Google's Sign In feature. If what you're looking is a lib for Google's one time password / authenticator I believe this can help: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/otp

Comment: Relevant link looks great, although at the very minimum you'll need a paragraph and even better a bit of code showing how this is more than just self promotion.

Comment: I'll look into it today; I've stumbled over the lib, but while it seems to allow to generate codes, I actually need to authenticate the codes. But I'll check it out further, maybe my question was unclear on that too.

Comment: Yes, OTP was the solution; I was looking in the wrong place, not realizing that it's not Google Authenticator I need to look up, but OTP instead! (I always missinterpreted OTP as a generic library to write your own authenticators... not realizing it's the same standard as the Google Authenticator)

Comment: Sorry, but I'm still missing something, how is it possible to verify that the codes that the google authenticator application gives me are valid from dart

Answer (score 4):

If anyone is looking for a dart library to use the secret key from Google authenticator to generate a matching token, the following library would help.

https://pub.dev/packages/dart_otp

```
Dependency: dart_otp: ^1.3.0

print(TOTP(secret: "<secret key>").now());
```

Comment: While the accepted answer generates OTP, as far as I see this answer also verifies the code taken from authenticator app.

Comment: When I am using this and passing OTP, it says - Invalid OTP. If I generate TOTP from PyOTP library of python it works but TOTP generated using flutter library doesn't work, any idea?